# How to find out which file/device is being pointed by a file descriptor N from a process?

Tags: linux

So I want to find out what does file descriptor "N" (say 4) means for process id . How can I do that using a Linux command?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [lsof](http://www.manpagez.com/man/8/lsof/):

```
[me@home]$ lsof -p 1990 -a -d 4
COMMAND    PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
unity-mus 1990  me    4u   CHR    1,3      0t0 5821 /dev/null
```

Explanation:

```
lsof -p 1990  -a   -d 4
     -------  ---  ----
        |      |     |
   PID=1990   AND   fd=4
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `lsof` (from man: lsof - list open files).
With `-d` option to file descriptors.

Answer (score 0):

If the process id is say `x`, look in `/proc/x/fd`. This folder has links to all files opened by a process.